# How to tell a browser that download is failed from Jetty servlet if an exception occurs during file transfer?

Tags: java, download, jetty

I have a Jetty servlet that allows users to download files from my internal file storage. 
In this servlet I'm writing small chunks of files into outputstream that is obtained via 
getOutputStream() method of HttpServletResponse object. Some exceptions could be thrown when writing to this outputstream.
The logic of a file transfer is quite complex, so exceptions can arise not only when connection is timeout or closed by a user.

The problem is that when exception occurs, no error message is shown in the browser to the user that downloads a file.
It just looks like download is finished successfully, but actually only first part of the file is downloaded.

What I want is to mark such a download as failed, so a browser will tell this to the user.

The first thing that comes to mind is to catch such exception and send error via sendError method of HttpServletResponse object,
or send redirect to error page. Unfortunatly, it does not work, because sendError method can be called only before the response is commited,
otherwise IllegalStateException is thrown. And response is already commited after first chunk flushing of response outputstream.

So, my question is how to tell a browser that downloading of a file is failed when an exception occurs during writing to a HttpServletResponse outputstream after the response is commited?